# average time being active

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I do have a json array, where i will be having id, starttime, endtime. I want to calculate average time being active by user. And some may have only startime but not endtime.
Example data -

```
data = [{"id":1, "stime":"2020-09-21T06:25:36Z","etime": "2020-09-22T09:25:36Z"},{"id":2, "stime":"2020-09-22T02:24:36Z","etime": "2020-09-23T07:25:36Z"},{"id":3, "stime":"2020-09-20T06:25:36Z","etime": "2020-09-24T09:25:36Z"},{"id":4, "stime":"2020-09-23T06:25:36Z","etime": "2020-09-29T09:25:36Z"}]
```

My method to achieve this, diff between startine and endtime. then total all difference time and divide by number of total num of Ids.

sample code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import dateutil.parser

datetimeFormat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
date_s_time = '2020-09-21T06:25:36Z'
date_e_time = '2020-09-22T09:25:36Z'
d1 = dateutil.parser.parse(date_s_time)
d2 = dateutil.parser.parse(date_e_time)
diff1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), datetimeFormat)\
    - datetime.datetime.strptime(d1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), datetimeFormat)
    
print("Difference 1:", diff1)

date_s_time2 = '2020-09-20T06:25:36Z'
date_e_time2 = '2020-09-28T02:25:36Z'
d3 = dateutil.parser.parse(date_s_time2)
d4 = dateutil.parser.parse(date_e_time2)
diff2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d4.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), datetimeFormat)\
    - datetime.datetime.strptime(d3.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), datetimeFormat)
 
print("Difference 2:", diff2)

print("total", diff1+diff2)

print(diff1+diff2/2)
```

please suggest me is there a better approach which will be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{"id":1, "stime":"2020-09-21T06:25:36Z","etime": "2020-09-22T09:25:36Z"},{"id":1, "stime":"2020-09-22T02:24:36Z","etime": "2020-09-23T07:25:36Z"},{"id":1, "stime":"2020-09-20T06:25:36Z","etime": "2020-09-24T09:25:36Z"},{"id":1, "stime":"2020-09-23T06:25:36Z"}]
```

(Let's say your last row has no end time)

Now, you can create a Pandas DataFrame using your data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df` looks like so:

```
   id                 stime                 etime
0   1  2020-09-21T06:25:36Z  2020-09-22T09:25:36Z
1   1  2020-09-22T02:24:36Z  2020-09-23T07:25:36Z
2   1  2020-09-20T06:25:36Z  2020-09-24T09:25:36Z
3   1  2020-09-23T06:25:36Z                   NaN
```

Now, we want to map the columns `stime` and `etime` so that the strings are converted to datetime objects, and fill `NaN`s with something that makes sense: if no end time exists, could we use the current time?

```
df = df.fillna(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))
df['etime'] = df['etime'].map(dateutil.parser.parse)
df['stime'] = df['stime'].map(dateutil.parser.parse)
```

Or, if you want to drop the rows that don't have an `etime`, just do

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Now `df` becomes:

```
   id                     stime                     etime
0   1 2020-09-21 06:25:36+00:00 2020-09-22 09:25:36+00:00
1   1 2020-09-22 02:24:36+00:00 2020-09-23 07:25:36+00:00
2   1 2020-09-20 06:25:36+00:00 2020-09-24 09:25:36+00:00
3   1 2020-09-23 06:25:36+00:00 2020-09-24 20:05:42+00:00
```

Finally, subtract the two:

```
df['tdiff'] = df['etime'] - df['stime']
```

and we get:

```
   id                     stime                     etime           tdiff
0   1 2020-09-21 06:25:36+00:00 2020-09-22 09:25:36+00:00 1 days 03:00:00
1   1 2020-09-22 02:24:36+00:00 2020-09-23 07:25:36+00:00 1 days 05:01:00
2   1 2020-09-20 06:25:36+00:00 2020-09-24 09:25:36+00:00 4 days 03:00:00
3   1 2020-09-23 06:25:36+00:00 2020-09-24 20:05:42+00:00 1 days 13:40:06
```

The mean of this column is:

```
df['tdiff'].mean()
Output: Timedelta('2 days 00:10:16.500000')
```

Comment: Thanks, what if any id dont have end time? Nonevalue etime and stime 2020-09-22T09:25:36Z

Comment: i don't wanna calculate if etime is None.. how can i achieve that

Comment: Thank you pranav